# How to filter items by _id in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I've made _ids by myself:
[image]

That function does not work:

```
router.get('/getCompetitions', (request, response) => {
    competitionTemplateCopy.find({"_id": 1})
    .then(data => response.json(data))
    .catch(error => response.json(error))
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
    competitionTemplateCopy.find(_id:1)
    .then(data => response.json(data))
    .catch(error => response.json(error))
});
```

And you should add  `_id: { type: Number, },` in your model